# How to reference a dll that take into account the configuration and platform

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

We are developing a library for MonoTouch, we could use in all other MonoTouch projects. For that purpose, we have generated 4 dlls that are depending on the configuration and the platform ( Debug / Release / iPhone / iPhoneSimulator).

Then, I am trying to include those dlls in an other MonoTouch project. In Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, the trick is to add one of the dll as reference of the project and then edit manually the project file.

E.g. for one Dll, we'll change the line that reference the Dll:

```
<Reference Include="Blabla" ...>
  ...
<HintPath>..\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Blabla.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The variable $(Platform) and $(Configuration) ensures we are taking the Dll corresponding the the right configuration and platform.

I did the same thing with a MonoDevelop project, but when I reload the modified project, the referenced Dll is in red (file not found). Somebody know why? Am I missing something in the configuration of the project / solution? Is the right way to do this?

Comment: This should work - might be a bug (or incomplete MSBuild compatibility issue) in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Actually not. I have the message: Assembly not available for Mono for iPhone (in Mono 2.10.8.1)